# Performing operations on substrings of text objects generated by D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm wondering about having narrative text paragraphs scrolling down the side of a webpage while the user is progressing through data visualisation.  As part of this it would be nice to add functionality to certain substrings of that text, for example to open a pop-up image it relates to.  But I cannot think of any way to tell D3 to objectify substrings of text elements so they can respond to operators like mouseover.

Here's an example, [plus jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/2q3by/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Substring click</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- example line -->
<p>The most interesting <A href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Most_Interesting_Man_in_the_World">man</A> in the world</p>
<div/>

<script type="text/javascript">

var link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Most_Interesting_Man_in_the_World";

d3.select("body").selectAll("div").append("text").text("The most interesting man in the world");

// is there any way to make 'man' link to 'wiki_link' or perform some other operation?

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, though you will need to format data in a way which is amenable to `d3`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2q3by/2/)

```js
var data = [{ text: 'The most interesting ', href: false },
            { text: 'man', href: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Most_Interesting_Man_in_the_World' },
            { text: ' in the world', href: false}];

var text = d3.select("body").selectAll("div").append("text");

text.selectAll('tspan')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('tspan')
  .html(function (d) { 
     return d.href 
       ? '<a href=' + encodeURI(d.href) + '>' + d.text + '</a>' 
       : d.text; 
   });
```

Comment: Thank you! Reckon I can figure out a way to format like this :)